# changing permissions of `nyccrash.txt': Operation not permitted

Tags: server, permissions, files, chown

I have an assignment to write PHP code, and upload the data to our school student's account. To make sure my script is working, I need to change the permissions on the files.

I am not a root because I am a student. How can I fix that problem?

```
chown: changing permissions of `nyccrash.txt': Operation not permitted
```

Those files has permission labeled as `apache`

The owner and user are apache, according to `ls -ls`

Thanks.

Comment: @surgemcgee Thanks for the input... we don't need to hear another version of Windows 7 vs Ubuntu vs MacOS. Every OS has its pros and cons. So is programming languages. Python has its own pros and cons. Pyramid (formerly Pylon) has its advantages and concerns when comparing with Django. I program Django on a daily basis. This is a system permission question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be able to fix this yourself and need help from the admin.

Renaming or copying the file should not be possible since your username is more than likely to be part of `others` (and not part of `user` or `group`).

Either your user has to be in the same group as the `apache` user or you need more permissions on only that file or you need to be a `sudoer`.